# Klocwork complains about unsigned to zero comparison that is always true -- WHY?

Tags: c++, gcc, comparison, klocwork

Klocwork says that "comparison of unsigned value against 0 is always true", on the following condition line:

```
#define MAX_VALUE 8589934592 //2^33
...
uint64_t val = get_val();
if (val >= MAX_VALUE)
{
  return ERROR_INVALID_VALUE;
}
```

Why? MAX_VALUE isn't 0...

Please advise.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [You're right MAX_VALUE is not zero](http://ideone.com/0MnQd). Use `const uint64_t MAX_VALUE = 2^33;`

Comment: The `val >= MAX_VALUE` is **true** for you ? What is the value of `get_val()`? And what is the declaration of `get_val()`?

Comment: MAX_VALUE is of type `int`. On most machines an `int` can't be that big.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: `2^33` is 35.  `^` is the bitwise xor operator.  C++ has no exponentation operator.  Try `1<<33`.

Comment: @BoPersson: Yes, but in `val >= MAX_VALUE`, since `val` is of type `uint64_t`, it should be promoted. ... Correction: integer literals are of whatever type is big enough to hold their values.

Comment: @MasoudM.: The value returned by `get_val()`, and its declared return type, can affect the value assigned to `val`, but not the warning.

Comment: @Keith Thompson: Click the link I've provided. Look for "output".

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: That's irrelevant to the OP's problem.  Your program uses the `^` bitwise xor operator.  The OP's code doesn't (it only appears in a comment).

Comment: @Keith Thompson: [Look at the edit history](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/8026797/revisions)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Ok, the original code did use `2^33`; I didn't see the question until after that was corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define MAX_VALUE 8589934592 //2^33
```

That literal might be a problem, depending on which version of C++ you're using and how your compiler chooses to treat it.

In the 2003 standard, an unsuffixed decimal literal is of type `int` if it's in the range of `int`, or of type `long int` if it's in the range of `long int`; otherwise, the behavior is undefined.  If your version of gcc conforms to the 2003 standard, the undefinedness of the behavior could likely manifest itself as `8589934592` evaluating to 0, which would explain the problem you're seeing.  (But I'd expect a warning about the integer literal being out of range; did you get such a warning?)

In the 2011 standard, such a literal can be of type `int`, `long`, or `long long`.  (C++ 2003 doesn't have `long long`; it was borrowed from C99.)

(Note that `^` is the bitwise xor operator; C++ has no exponentation operator.  That doesn't matter much in a comment, but `2**33` might be clearer, even though that's not a valid C++ expression either.)

```
...
uint64_t val = get_val();
```

What type does `get_val()` return?  That shouldn't affect the warning, but it would be interesting to know.

```
if (val >= MAX_VALUE)
```

If `long` is 64 bits on your system, then this should be ok.  If `long` is 32 bits, then `uint64_t` would have to be something wider than `long` / `unsigned long` -- which implies that your compiler is not operating in conforming C++ 2003 mode.

What output do you get for the following program?

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

uint64_t get_val();

const char *type_name(int i) { return "int"; }
const char *type_name(long i) { return "long"; }
const char *type_name(unsigned long i) { return "unsigned long"; }
const char *type_name(long long i) { return "long long"; }
const char *type_name(unsigned long long i) { return "unsigned long long"; }

int main() {
    std::cout << "UINT_MAX   = " << UINT_MAX << "\n";
    std::cout << "ULONG_MAX  = " << ULONG_MAX << "\n";
    std::cout << "8589934592 = " << 8589934592 << "\n";
    std::cout << "8589934592 is of type " << type_name(8589934592) << "\n";

    uint64_t val = time(0);
    if (val >= 8589934592) {
        std::cout << "It's getting late!\n";
    }
}
```

*and* what warning, if any, does Klocwork give you on the comparison?  If Klockwork gives you a warning that's inconsistent with the output of the program, this could be a bug in Klocwork (which you should report) -- or you might just need to invoke it with different options.  (I've never used Klocwork myself.)

You might be able to solve (or at least work around) the problem by invoking g++ with `-std=c++0x`.

Comment: Since the warning is from Klocwork, it's more related to _its_ interpretation of the C++ standard. It's a good point, though, the code is non-portable and a tool like Klocwork has every right to warn about that.

Comment: @MSalters: Good point.  I've updated my answer to address that possibility.

Answer (score 0):

Tools like Klocwork has a certain rate of "False Positive", usually 15%, but up to 50% in some cases,  actually a large part of my job is to look at output of Static Code Analysis Tools and decide if the error they reporting are False Positive(or if there is False Negatives )

To cut a long story short, show us the prototype of get_val() and tell me what types it should return and I will see why it reports that message  and if it is a FP.

Answer (score 0):

Alternative solution without big numbers (avoiding the size-of-literal problem)

```
const int MAX_VALUE_LOG2 = 33;
...
uint64_t val = get_val();
if ( (val >> MAX_MAX_VALUE_LOG2) > 0)
{
  return ERROR_INVALID_VALUE;
}
```